# react-native app splash screen is showing

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a react-native app in VS Code. The app is running fine in the browser with expo.

The .apk can be installed on my Android tablet. But after starting the app, the splash screen is shown, staying forever (see image).

[image: Text]

Things I have tried:

> enable clear text traffic and changing the url of API call to http

> import react-native-splash-screen, and call SplashScreen.hide() once data fetch is complete

When I outcomment the axios call, the app is working normally and the splash screen disappears.

Code is as follows.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
   state = {
      products: []
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.GetAllProducts();
   }

   GetAllProducts() {

         axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/getallproducts').then((response) => {
            this.setState({
               products: response.data
           });
          });
   }

   getsrcPath(string) { // this function distinguishes between images in UserImages folder and images on Cloudinary
      var firstChar = string.charAt(0);
      if (firstChar == '~') { // image is in UserImages folder and item.picture path starts wih ~/UserImages/
         return string.substring(1, string.length);
      }
      else { // image is at Cloudinary and item.picture starts with http://
         return string;
      }
   }

   render() {
      return (
         this.state.products && <View>
            {
               this.state.products.map((item, index) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                     key = {item.id}
                     style = {styles.container}>
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>{item.productname}</Text>
                     <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                     <Text>€ {item.price}</Text>
                     <img src={this.getsrcPath(item.picture)} />
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>
                        {item.name}
                     </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               ))
            }
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      padding: 10,
      marginTop: 3,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      cursor: 'none'
   },
   text: {
      color: '#4f603c'
   }
})
```

/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.reactnativeapp2">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

  <queries>
    <!-- Support checking for http(s) links via the Linking API -->
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries>

  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

--edit--

I finally got a solution. I built simple error handling into the axios .get, like this, with a catch():

```
         axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/getallproducts')
         .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            this.setState({
               products: response.data
           });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            alert(error.message);
          });
```

Now, when running the app on Android, I get an alert with the message:

```
this.setState is not a function
```

Appearently, react-native expects an arrow function that calls this.setState. As a workaround, I managed to call this.setState with the simple switch of the keyword this, as follows:

```
   GetAllProducts() {
         let that = this;

         axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/getallproducts')
         .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            that.setState({
               products: response.data
           });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            alert(error.message);
          });
   }
```

Comment: Are you running App.js as home screen? 
 If not  I think you are view Android Splash Screen on mobile. Check Android Code if there is intent present ?

Comment: The description is no proper

Comment: Use dependency react-native-splash-screen. 
And call SplashScreen.hide() once data fetch complete.